# Git config error on setup multiple ssh on github

Tags: git, github, ssh

I am trying to setup my git config to choose the ssh that corresponds to each case

```
Host github.com_enterprise
    Hostname github.com
    User user_enterprise@enterprise.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_enterprise_ssh

Host github.com_personal
    Hostname github.com
    User user_personal@personal.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_personal_ssh
```

or

```
Host github.com:enterprise
    Hostname github.com
    User user_enterprise@enterprise.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_enterprise_ssh

Host github.com:personal
    Hostname github.com
    User user_personal@personal.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_personal_ssh
```

I have found that the host was supposed to be the alias but it doesn't work. For example, if want to make git clone works with id_enterprise_ssh what I have to do is

```
Host github.com
    Hostname github.com
    User user_enterprise@enterprise.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_enterprise_ssh
```

I have to edit the host by deleting the `_enterprise` and deleting the other `github.com_personal` information. So, I wonder what I am missing in my config setup

Answer (score 1):

When you use ssh via something like `git clone git@github.com:your-username/your-repo.git`, SSH is looking for `github.com` to match the `Host <X>` alias, *not* the Hostname value. So, if you use the first option for ssh_config, your SSH-related commands should look like:

`git clone git@github.com_personal:<org>/<repo>.git`

Note that once you start doing this, you may have to make sure your remote-urls are configured correctly (that is, that they say `github.com_personal` and `github.com_enterprise`). You can check with `git remote -v`. You also have to make sure all of the relevant SSH keys are added to your SSH-agent.

Comment: yes but my problem is with git clone. So, I am kind of confuse it looks like I cannot have two differente ssh declaration on my global git config? My personal github is `github.com/ggalvez92` and the enterprise should look like `github.com/enterprise`

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. 

With an SSH-config like:

```Host github.com_personal
    Hostname github.com
    User user_personal@personal.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_personal_ssh```

You need to edit your git clone commands to be `git clone git@github.com_personal:<yourusername>/<your_repo>.git`

Answer (score 1):

Considering an SSH URL for `github.com` will always use `git@` as a remote user, do replace in each of your Host entry a line:

```
User git
```

That way, you can test each of your Host entry wtih

```
ssh -Tv github.com_personal
ssh -Tv github.com_enterprise
```

In both instances, you should see a welcome message with the right perosnal or enterprise username in it.

Comment: I have tried like this
```
Host github.com/enterprise
 User git
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_enterprise

Host github.com/ggalvez92
 User git
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ggalvez92
```
but it is not working

Comment: @GianPierreGálvez I would not recommend using a `Host` entry with a `/`. Use `Host ghEnterprise` and `Host ghGgalvez92`. Then test with `ssh -Tv ghEnterprise`

Comment: I have try using `github.com:ggalvez92` because a clone example of my user is `git@github.com:ggalvez92/{PROJECTNAME}.git` . By the way, I am on windows 10 so I don't know if I have to do extra steps.

Comment: @GianPierreGálvez The URL to use is `ghGgalvez92:ggalvez92/{PROJECTNAME}.git`. But first, make sure you see your name when doing a `ssh -Tv ghGgalvez92` (assuming you have a `Host` entry name '`ghGgalvez92`' in your `%USERPROFILE%/.ssh/config`). And yes, it does work on Windows 10.

Comment: I got `Bad owner or permissions on C:\\Users\\PC/.ssh/config`

Comment: @GianPierreGálvez Are you executing this as admin? (in a CMD launched as admin?)